# cpufreq-info frequency range max speed never goes back to original maximum after plugging back the power coord

Tags: drivers, intel, performance, cpu, turbo-boost

On boot `cpufreq-info` gives me these values (for brevity I'll print just the first core, but the rest look the same):

```bash
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
  hardware limits: 400 MHz - 4.20 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 400 MHz and 4.20 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 800 MHz.
```

When I unplug the power cord, the max frequency drops to 1.9 GHz

```bash
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
  hardware limits: 400 MHz - 4.20 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 400 MHz and 1.90 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 800 MHz.
```

Which would be OK to save the battery, but when plugging the cord back, the maximum value of the range stays the same:

```bash
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
  hardware limits: 400 MHz - 4.20 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 400 MHz and 1.90 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 800 MHz.
```

Can I do something to make it go back to the original 4.2 GHz value? The BIOS has been restarted to it's defaults.

Given the spec below, my understanding is that the "base frequency" of this [i7-8650U CPU](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/124968/intel-core-i78650u-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-20-ghz.html) is 1.9 GHz, and the "max turbo frequency" is 4.2 GHz. And so my suspicion is that there is a bug somewhere (in the `intel_pstate` driver?) that ignores the turbo?

#### My specs are:

Laptop Lenovo T480
Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Intel® Core™ [i7-8650U CPU](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/124968/intel-core-i78650u-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-20-ghz.html) @ 1.90GHz × 8
Linux t480 5.15.0-46-generic #49~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 4 19:15:44 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

#### Other

I also tried to set the governor to "performance" after re-plugging the cord, but that did not do anything with the max of the range either:

```bash
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
  hardware limits: 400 MHz - 4.20 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 400 MHz and 1.90 GHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 1.30 GHz.
```

Comment: I agree it seems to be turbo being disabled. Check via `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo`. I disagree that it is a bug in the intel_pstate CPU frequency scaling driver. Something outside of the driver needs to enable turbo again. Try: `echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo`

Comment: @DougSmythies you're right, doing `echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo` fixed the issue! :-) . Still _feels_ like a bug though, because this disabling of the turbo doesn't happen on an explicit request. It happens when the charger is unplugged. I personally would have expected the UX to be such that it's reenabled when the charger is plugged back in. Can I set it up to do so?

Comment: Well, we would have to figure out what is disabling turbo in the first place, and if it is somehow misconfigured to not enable it again. I do not know what that would be, unless it is tlp? Are you running tlp?

Comment: @DougSmythies That was it! I do have `tlp` enabled, I'm new to all this CPU utilization and I must have enabled it as part of following some other SO instructions and then forgot about it :-/ . I edited the `/etc/tlp.conf` file and uncommented `CPU_BOOST_ON_AC=1` line (`CPU_BOOST_ON_BAT="0"` was already uncommented), rebooted and now the boost frequency is reenabled after I plug the AC cord back.

Comment: Somewhat interesting still is that this behavior seems consistent with other `tlp` options: I had `CPU_MAX_PERF_ON_BAT="30"` and `CPU_MAX_PERF_ON_AC` commented out, when I plugged the power cord back to the PC, the "current CPU frequency" would still not go past 1.2 GHz (which is about just a little lower than 30% of 4.2 GHz). Uncommenting and setting `CPU_MAX_PERF_ON_AC=100` fixed that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key information for this question was the base CPU frequency of 1.90 GHz and the max Turbo frequency of 4.20 GHz, giving the hint that turbo boost might be disabled upon unplugging the charger from the LapTop based on the provided information.

When using the intel_pstate CPU frequency scaling driver, the primitive way to check is:

```
doug@s19:~$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
1
```

Where 1 indicates turbo frequencies are disabled and 0 indicates turbo frequencies are available to be requested and used as required.

So the question becomes: What service or task disabled turbo upon unplugging the LapTop charger and why wasn't turbo enabled when the charger was plugged in?

It seems, at least in some cases, that the tlp service configuration is the culprit. If by user or default, I don't know. The relevant area of the `/etc/tlp.conf` file is:

```
# Set the CPU "turbo boost" feature: 0=disable, 1=allow
# Requires an Intel Core i processor.
# Important:
# - This may conflict with your distribution's governor settings
# - A value of 1 does *not* activate boosting, it just allows it
# Default: <none>

#CPU_BOOST_ON_AC=1
CPU_BOOST_ON_BAT=0
```

So, one needs to uncomment the "CPU_BOOST_ON_AC=1" line to activate it after service restart or reboot.

From the question comments, there seems to have been an additional issue with tlp configuration. The relevant area of the `/etc/tlp.conf` file:

```
# Set Intel CPU P-state performance: 0..100 (%).
# Limit the max/min P-state to control the power dissipation of the CPU.
# Values are stated as a percentage of the available performance.
# Requires an Intel Core i processor with intel_pstate driver.
# Default: <none>

CPU_MAX_PERF_ON_AC="100"
CPU_MAX_PERF_ON_BAT="30"
```

Where it seems the OP originally had the "CPU_MAX_PERF_ON_AC" commented out.